# How to set value of child pop op elements from parent window using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-8

I am calling a pop up window from a parent page using :

```
var childWindow = open('test1.aspx', '1397127848655', 'resizable=no,width=700,height=500');
```

I then try to set the value of two spans which are on chil pop up from parent window using this `childWindow` object.

```
 childWindow.onload = function () {
alert('this msg does not shows up when run on IE8');
                var hidden1 = childWindow.document.getElementById('hidden1');
                var hidden2 = childWindow.document.getElementById('hidden2');
                hidden1.innerHTML = rowindex;
                hidden2.innerHTML = controlname;
            };
```

this code works fine as long as I am using chrome. But it refuses to work on IE8. There are no console errors either.

I tried removing `childWindow.onload = function () { }` but then the page would just sort of refresh on both chrome and IE8.

**UPDATE**
This did not work either.

```
   function CallPopUp(rowindex,controlname ) {
            function popupLoad() {
                alert('this msg does not shows up when run on IE8');
                var hidden1 = childWindow.document.getElementById('hidden1');
                var hidden2 = childWindow.document.getElementById('hidden2');
                hidden1.innerHTML = rowindex;
                hidden2.innerHTML = controlname;
            }

            var childWindow = open('test1.aspx', '1397127848655', 'resizable=no,width=700,height=500');
            if (childWindow.document.readyState === "complete") {
                popupLoad();
            } else {
                childWindow.onload = popupLoad;
            }
```

Comment: what is type of hidden?

Comment: its just a span.. with class named hidden. It is visible at the moment.I am planning on giving it css style hidden later on

Comment: @Adil This code works fine on chrome. But when I run this on IE8 the span remains blank.

Comment: @Adil it seems that the function is not even getting executed on IE8 since I put alert at the first line and it did not show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `test.aspx` is in the browser cache, it is possible that the `onload` event has already happened before you attach your event handler so you're missing it (IE is known to do this with image load events).  I'd suggest you check `document.readyState` before attaching your event handler.

```
function popupLoad() {
    alert('this msg does not shows up when run on IE8');
    var hidden1 = childWindow.document.getElementById('hidden1');
    var hidden2 = childWindow.document.getElementById('hidden2');
    hidden1.innerHTML = rowindex;
    hidden2.innerHTML = controlname;
}

var childWindow = open('test1.aspx', '1397127848655', 'resizable=no,width=700,height=500');
if (childWindow.document.readyState === "complete") {
    popupLoad();
} else {
    childWindow.onload = popupLoad;
}
```

---

As another option, you can put the values into the query parameters for the URL:

```
`"test1.aspx?hidden1=" + rowindex + "&hidden2=" + controlname`
```

and then have the popup window load it's own fields from it's own `onload` handler from what's in the query string. Then, you can keep the code in the popup window self contained and you don't have to try to modify one window from another.

If you don't want the user to see this or be able to edit it, you can turn off the location bar in the popup window.

Comment: check my update. I tried your code but it did not work

Comment: @Arbaaz - not much we can do but issue blind guesses if you can't show us the actual running page URL with the issue.  Actual debugging requires a running example.

Comment: I know. 
Well if you have to set value of child pop up window's span with values from parent window. How would you do it?

Comment: @Arbaaz - One way to do it is to put the values into the query parameters for the URL `"test1.aspx?hidden1=" + rowindex + "&hidden2=" + controlname` and then have the popup window load it's own fields from it's own onload handler from what's in the query string.  Then, you can keep the code in the popup window self contained and you don't have to try to modify one window from another.  I'm sure you can modify one window from another (with the same origin), but I can't see what your issue is without being able to debug it.

Comment: I know but I dont want to edit url in some browser which might allow it.

Comment: @Arbaaz - I've offered you a work-around and you haven't offered enough info for us to help you further or something we can debug.  Not much else we can do here.

Comment: What you have offered is helpful and appreciated. I am now doing it the way you have suggested. I wonder if its possible to make sure that user can not edit url in pop up on any browser. 
Edit your answer and add what you have posted as a comment, I will be marking your answer soon.

Comment: @Arbaaz - info from my comments added to my answer.